# npm publish / npm install - auth token invalidation

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-login

I think NPM is struggling with security a bit today, when I run `npm install` on a local project, I get:

> 'npm WARN notice Due to a recent security incident, all user tokens
>   have been invalidated. Please see
>   https://status.npmjs.org/incidents/dn7c1fgrr7ng for more details. To
>   generate a new token, visit https://www.npmjs.com/settings/~/tokens or
>   run "npm login"

I signed in again with `npm login`, but I get the same error. Does anyone know of a workaround?

Comment: got the same issue here too! the new token doesn't work :/

Answer (score 8):

I get same warning even after the new login:

[image]

I get that if the package name is incorrect, on top of the 404 error.

If you need to be logged in just log back in.

If you don't need to be logged in just **check that you have the correct package name**.

In my case `react-native-create-app` didn't exist.. After adding the correct name: `create-react-native-app` it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have your npmrc file set up ok.
https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc

Answer (score 3):

Steps to follow:

1. Run `npm login`
2. Enter your

   1. Username
   2. Password
   3. Email address

   Note: if you don't have this credentials, you have to sign up at https://www.npmjs.com/signup
3. Run `npm install bootstrap --save`

This should work.

Answer (score 2):

After performing `npm login` try to reopen CLI you are using in order to run npm commands. It worked for me